# How can I find out the version of an installed grunt module?

Tags: module, command, version, gruntjs

Just wondering what is the command to verify the currently installed version of any grunt module already installed using command line. For example

```
grunt-compass -v
```

Or

```
grunt-compass --version
```

do not work.

Answer (score 38):

Use

```
npm list --depth=0
```

You can also use `grep` to look for a specific package

```
npm list --depth=0 | grep grunt-contrib-compass
```

[image: command.png]

There is an `npm ls` alias, for short.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps you can try this, it worked for me.

```
grunt -version
```

Comment: This will display the current Grunt verison, not any "Grunt module" version

Answer (score 1):

With Python you can do something like this, in the root of your project, remembering to substitute grunt-contrib-compass for any other package installed with npm.

```
cat node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/package.json | python -c "import json, sys; print json.load(sys.stdin)['version']"
```

This is not my code, I've adapted it from here - [Parsing Json data columnwise in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511851/parsing-json-data-columnwise-in-shell) - but I've tested it and it works. :-)

If you'd rather a node/grunt solution, [you can have a look at my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200367/how-do-i-get-a-grunt-projects-version-from-command-line/20203747#20203747). It's based on the project's `package.json`, but you could adapt that to use one in the `node_modules` directory.

Edit: After reading Nico's answer, you could transform that output with sed to print just the version number, like so:

```
npm list --depth=0 | grep grunt-contrib-compass | sed "s/[^0-9\.]//g"
```